Maximum principle for $\partial_t u = e^{-u}\Delta u$ on 2-manifolds
Assuming $(M,g)$ is a compact 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $u(t,x):(0,\infty)\times M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfy
$$
\partial_t u = e^{-u}\Delta u 
\tag{1}
$$
then, how to show there is a constant $C$ such that $-C\le u\le C$ ?
I use to the scalar maximum principle, namely, using the solution of a ODE to control the solution of PDE, but it is effective for
$$
\partial_t u =\Delta u +...
$$
which is not liking the (1).
I find (1) can become
$$
\partial_t e^u = e^{-u}\Delta e^u -e^{-2u}|\nabla e^u|^2
$$
It seems like a step in the right direction, but I'm tired today, so I  think about it tomorrow or later.

Picture below is from The Ricci flow on surfaces. The problem is from the red line of the picture.



Weak maximum principle for scalars



The parabolic maximum principle works for equations of the form $\partial _t u = e^f \Delta u$.

@ArcticChar  The parabolic maximum principle says when the extreme value is taken at the boundary, or when it is a constant function. Seemly, we can't get the boundary from them.

@ArcticChar Could you detail talk about it, or give me a reference, or detail keyword ?  I find my way doesn't work, and I don't understand yours, since I feel the parabolic weak or strong maximum principle is not effect.

See proposition 7.2 in "The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry" by Ben Andrews and Christopher Hopper. In the statement they assume $\partial_t u - \Delta u \ge 0$, but the exact same proof applies.

@ArcticChar  Thanks, it is useful. And it should be proposition 6.2.
